# Extract all pages as single from a pdf with pdftk

Tags: linux, unix

how can I extract single pages from a pdf using pdftk commands? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From the quick look at the pdftk [homepage](https://www.pdflabs.com/t/pdftk/)

For example if you want to extract 11th page then you can do it like this

`pdftk A=full-pdf.pdf cat A11 output outfile_p11.pdf`

Comment: I voted this answer up because it _seemed_ to retain the "properties" of the original document.  This was important to me because I wanted to reproduce a problem I was having with a document, but wanted to reproduce the problem on a smaller file.  This is in contrast with extracting a single page using OSX->Preview.